# GIT => Manage multiple repository in same visual studio 2017 solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have many projects (PRJ1, PRJ2, ..) who reference "Libraries projects" (DLL1, DLL2, ...).

I want open Solution1 in Visual Studio who contains PRJ1 and DLL1. And when i commit change, it push on PRJ1 repository and DLL1 repository.
If an another user have only DLL1 opened on his computer, he can see the changes pushed when he synchronise.
And if he push changes, i can see them if i'm synchronised my solution.

I tried with Submodules and Subtrees (since three days) but i can't have this result.

Could you help me with a simple procedure please ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what is written about [Syncing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing)

> Git is designed to give each developer an entirely isolated development environment. This means that information is not automatically passed back and forth between repositories. Instead, developers need to manually pull upstream commits into their local repository or manually push their local commits back up to the central repository. The git remote command is really just an easier way to pass URLs to these "sharing" commands.

Comment: Ok, i understand that it's not possible to create "Arbored solution" on server.
I understand too the "remote" command is may a solution. 
but is it possible to reference multiple "remote" in same VS solution and commit all in one action ?
After, Maybe can i make a batch for "install" the solution on client" 0_0